# After adding a new event, can't select textbox to type in

Tags: html, angular, typescript, syncfusion, ejs-schedule

I am using Syncfusion in an Angular app. After I create an event, I can no longer edit any fields in the event editor unless I click on a dropdown I added manually. I will add the code which I am using to add the dropdown.

Here are some things to note:

- I am calling syncfusion's `openEditor` with the proper parameters.
- I have made sure 2 editors aren't popping up.
- I have double checked CSS properties, ensuring that the textbox is enabled.
- I am able to use tab to have the cursor on the textbox, and can edit the values from there. Saving works here too.
- Only non-text items are editable. I can click on date selectors, colour pickers, etc... Just text I cannot click on.

The strange thing is that I am adding multiselect dropdowns in the same way and I do not need to click on those to then get access to edit the other fields.

```
      // Driller
      let drillerElement: HTMLInputElement = args.element.querySelector(
        "#drillerInput"
      ) as HTMLInputElement;

      if (!drillerElement.classList.contains("e-dropdown")) {
        this.drillerDropdown = new DropDownList({
          placeholder: "Choose driller",
          value: eventData.UserResponsibleID,
          dataSource: this.peopleResources,
          fields: { text: "ResourceName", value: "UserID" },
          floatLabelType: "Auto",
        });

        this.drillerDropdown.query = this.getQueryForResources(
          this.getListOfAvailablePeople(
            eventData["StartTime"],
            eventData["EndTime"],
            eventData
          )
        );

        this.drillerDropdown.dataBind();
        this.drillerDropdown.appendTo(drillerElement);
        drillerElement.setAttribute("name", "UserResponsibleID");

        // Handle the change event to update the UserResponsibleID
        this.drillerDropdown.change = (args) => {
          eventData.UserResponsibleID = this.drillerDropdown.value as number;
        };
      }
```

I have already tried to change the call to openEditor, checking CSS styling, removing the dropdown causing issues, and adding said dropdown in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, please remove the below mentioned line. If the issue still persists, you can check by removing properties from the dropdown list component one by one.

```
this.drillerDropdown.query = this.getQueryForResources(
this.getListOfAvailablePeople(eventData["StartTime"], eventData["EndTime"],eventData));
```

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-list-frxfxv?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp.module.ts,index.html